# Python/Pandas - Unstack or Melt multidimensional table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a beginning to the language issue with unpivoting a table. I'm hoping that it's just a vocabulary thing and I'll be off and running.  I have a table with three dimensions, within the dimensions, there are three elements and this table covers three time periods.  The tables that I work with are more complex than that, but this one is already ridiculously wide.

| male_female | Total | Total | Total | Total | Total | Total | Total | Total | Total | M | M | M | M | M | M | M | M | M | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| adult_youth | Total | Total | Total | A | A | A | Y | Y | Y | Total | Total | Total | A | A | A | Y | Y | Y | Total | Total | Total | A | A | A | Y | Y | Y |
| urban_rural | Total | U | R | Total | U | R | Total | U | R | Total | U | R | Total | U | R | Total | U | R | Total | U | R | Total | U | R | Total | U | R |
| 2021 | 46 | 22 | 24 | 22 | 11 | 11 | 24 | 11 | 13 | 22 | 8 | 14 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 17 | 7 | 10 | 24 | 14 | 10 | 17 | 10 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| 2020 | 48 | 22 | 26 | 22 | 11 | 11 | 26 | 11 | 15 | 26 | 10 | 16 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 19 | 8 | 11 | 22 | 12 | 10 | 15 | 9 | 6 | 7 | 3 | 4 |
| 2019 | 50 | 22 | 28 | 22 | 11 | 11 | 28 | 11 | 17 | 30 | 12 | 18 | 9 | 3 | 6 | 21 | 9 | 12 | 20 | 10 | 10 | 13 | 8 | 5 | 7 | 2 | 5 |

I want it to look like:

|  | year | male_female | adult_youth | urban_rural | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021 | Total | Total | Total | 46 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 40 | 2020 | M | A | U | 2 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 80 | 2019 | F | Y | R | 5 |

I'm just at a loss on how to transpose it into something that can be pivoted or crosstabbed  with modifications. I've tried stack and unstack, melt, transpose, wide_to_long, but I just can't get the syntax, or the procedure for peeling off layer. This has been a manual process, but it's somethat that if I could master, would allow me to use Excel and Tableau less, and get more done.

Comment: What does your original table *actually* look like, paste the version you get from `print(df)` formatted as code. It's impossible to tell exactly what sort of MultiIndex columns going on or not.

Comment: Don't reply here, edit your question~

Comment: Change `pd.read_csv(...` to `pd.read_csv('df_pivoted.csv', header=[0,1,2], index_col=[0])` like I have below.

Comment: Thank you! In two lines of code, you have done what I was not able with hours of spaghetti code and Dr. Googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a Multi-Dimensional Table in CSV format:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df_pivoted.csv', header=[0,1,2], index_col=[0])

...

male_female Total                                         M                                      F
adult_youth Total             A             Y         Total             A           Y        Total             A            Y
urban_rural Total   U   R Total   U   R Total   U   R Total   U   R Total  U  R Total  U   R Total   U   R Total   U  R Total  U  R
2021           46  22  24    22  11  11    24  11  13    22   8  14     5  1  4    17  7  10    24  14  10    17  10  7     7  4  3
2020           48  22  26    22  11  11    26  11  15    26  10  16     7  2  5    19  8  11    22  12  10    15   9  6     7  3  4
2019           50  22  28    22  11  11    28  11  17    30  12  18     9  3  6    21  9  12    20  10  10    13   8  5     7  2  5
```

Doing:

```
df.index.name = 'year'
out = df.unstack().reset_index(name='value')
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   male_female adult_youth urban_rural  year  value
0        Total       Total       Total  2021     46
1        Total       Total       Total  2020     48
2        Total       Total       Total  2019     50
3        Total       Total           U  2021     22
4        Total       Total           U  2020     22
..         ...         ...         ...   ...    ...
76           F           Y           U  2020      3
77           F           Y           U  2019      2
78           F           Y           R  2021      3
79           F           Y           R  2020      4
80           F           Y           R  2019      5
```